# looks like Vandermonde determinant

Tags: matrices

Calculate the determinant of $M = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
1 & a & a^2 \\
1 & b & b^2 \\
1 & c & c^2 \\
\end{array}} \right)\;$.

How can one calculate this? Is there a general method like in the case of Vandermonde determinants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the transpose of a matrix has the same determinant as the original matrix. Thus, whether you have "rows"  or "columns" does not change anything; you can apply the result for Vandermonde determinants you seem to know.